# Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2, backend

After Magento 2 installation, when I logged in to the backend not even a single option is working.Unable to select any option at the side tab.Kindy anyone guide me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's look like that you have problem with css and js assets. Check permissions for your Apache/Nginx user for modifying pub/static/ folder. Additional, you may create assets manually running  `php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` shell command
from project root directory.